# Combining 3 separate columns into one for it to be used in an IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This is purely an efficiency question. I have two tables:

One where user IDs are stored based on their position within an entity

```
id     | supervisor     | manager      | worker
-------+----------------+--------------+---------------
1      | 12             | 15           | 32
2      | 12             | 42           | 22
```

And the one with the user info:

```
id     | name           | email
-------+----------------+---------------------
12     | Bob            | bob@example.com
15     | Dave           | dave@example.com
```

Is it possible to do this with only one `IN` clause instead of 3?

```
SELECT `name`, `email` 
FROM `tbl_users` 
WHERE `id` IN 
(SELECT `supervisor` FROM `tbl_warehouse` WHERE `id` = 'WAREHOUSEID') 
OR `id` IN 
(SELECT `manager` FROM `tbl_warehouse` WHERE `id` = 'WAREHOUSEID')
OR `id` IN 
(SELECT `worker` FROM `tbl_warehouse` WHERE `id` = 'WAREHOUSEID')
```

I tried a few things trying to combine the `supervisor`, `manager`, `worker` columns into one column so the `IN` clause works but did so without success

Comment: if `'WAREHOUSEID'` is a parameter, you better use like this `@warehouseid` other wise looks like you are mixing string with numbers

Comment: I just threw `WAREHOUSEID` in this in as an example. That's a parameter that I set with a prepared statement

Comment: I know, is just a tip for the next time. Also in your question you show two table but dont say the name, of course after seem the query you can guess. But is better if you make clear from start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` and use the `IN` inside the subquery:

```
select `name`,
    `email`
from `tbl_users` u
where exists (
        select 1
        from `tbl_warehouse` w
        where w.id = 'WAREHOUSEID'
            and u.id in (w.supervisor, w.manager, w.worker)
        )
```

You achieve this using `JOIN` too:

```
select u.name, u.email
from tbl_users u
join tbl_warehouse w on u.id in (w.supervisor, w.manager, w.worker)
where w.id = 'WAREHOUSEID'
```

Comment: The `EXISTS` worked wonderfully. Learned something really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or, also:

```
SELECT
  name
, email
FROM tbl_users u
JOIN (
          SELECT supervisor FROM tbl_warehouse WHERE id = 'WAREHOUSEID'
UNION ALL SELECT manager    FROM tbl_warehouse WHERE id = 'WAREHOUSEID'
UNION ALL SELECT worker     FROM tbl_warehouse WHERE id = 'WAREHOUSEID'
) w(id)
USING(id);
```

And make sure, as already said elsewhere, that you join INTEGERs with INTEGERs ...